# Why editorjs ( rich text editor) is not working with textarea tag?

Tags: reactjs, textarea, rich-text-editor, editorjs

I am trying to incorporate editorjs in my react app. I incorporated it with the **div** element with **contentEditable="true"**. I want to implement the text editor with the **textarea** element also but it seems it's not working.

Is there anything extra to be done in order to implement the rich-text-editor on **textarea** tag.
Using the id of the element on the holder element of editorjs is not helping me with **textarea** tag.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/editorjs-is-not-working-with-textarea
I referred to the link above and unfortunately, it's not helping me.

I am pretty new to implementing this stuff, Does anyone know the issue?
Thanks